# Why is subreport inside main report showing a line when sub report is blank?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have created table view inside main report.

Inside table row I am taking sub-report, when sub-report having data it works perfectly but when sub-report is empty it showing one black color line inside table row.

I had set the properties for sub-report **'remove line when blank= true'** it is working in only sub report, but when I am compiling main report it showing one line.

**This is my output** [image: Current result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the subreport, you need to

1. `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"` in mainreport on the subreport's, `reportElement` tag
2. `whenNoDataType="NoPages"` in subreport on the `jasperReports` tag (or remove attribute, default is NoPages

Comment: I already tried this but in ireport preview it showing the lines for subreport.

Comment: Then pass some jrxml in question edit it to create a [mcve], because if your datasource is empty this will work, I have done it a lot of time, assuming that the lines are in the subreport. (note isRemove is in main report and whenNoData in subreport).